# Prove $\lim_{x \to x_0}{f(x)}=f(x_0)$ for f that is defined in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ and for every ${a_n}$ which approaches x_0 $f(a_n)$ converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, continuity

Given $f$ which is defined in some neighbourhood of $x_0$, and given that for every sequence $a_n$ which approaches $x_0$ $f(a_n)$ converges, prove that $\lim_{x \to x_0}{f(x)}=f(x_0)$

Apart from the proof, I would also like to ask, is this not a version of Heine's definition for limits which requires less knowledge about the function? Why is this not the one used?

Comment: Prove by contradiction.

Comment: $f$ must be continuous.

Comment: How do I achieve the contradiction?

Comment: It is the Heine's version of *continuity* of $f$ at $x_0$. Thus it requires *more* to be true about the function than the Heine's definition of the limit, not less. In the definition of the limit, $f(x_0)$ need not even be defined, much less be the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to x_0$.

Comment: But I am not told what limit does $f(a_n)$ converge to and so it could be that for two different sequences: ${a_n}, {b_n}$ which both converge to $x_0$ the sequences: $f(a_n)$ and $f(b_n)$ converge to completely different limits.

Comment: Sorer: in the form it is written the claim is wrong. Where did you get it from? Check all the hypothesis

Comment: @Icv I got the claim as part of a problem set from university. The theorem is supposedly correct, do you think it could be disproved?